# How are regular DOM Elements mutable?

Tags: dom, reactjs

In the react docs, they claim:

> ReactElements are not to be confused with DOM Elements. A ReactElement
>   is a light, stateless, immutable, virtual representation of a DOM
>   Element.

Does this imply that a regular DOM element can be mutated? And if so, can you give an example of how you can mutate a DOM element, but the same code applied to a ReactElement would not mutate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I think this has to do with the virtual DOM.

The virtual DOM is all about "diffing" to find the differences (if any) among its ReactElements. If ReactElements could be mutated, then the virtual DOM wouldn't need to diff, as the element would just mutate itself and that would be the current state of the virtual DOM. But the virtual DOM wants to diff, so rather than updating the existing ReactElement, what happens is you pass the virtual DOM a new version of that ReactElement. And updating itself to the most recent version (sort of like git I guess), the virtual DOM then updates the real DOM with the most recent version of itself.

**The full flow looks something like this (I think)**

React takes your stateful `ReactComponent` (i.e. it can be mutated), turns it into a statless ReactElement(s) (i.e. if something changes, it issues a new ReactElement rather than updating the old one), which are used to create your virtual DOM. If state changes in your ReactComponent, a new version of the corresponding ReactElements are created and sent to the virtual DOM. The virtual DOM runs the new version of the ReactElements against the old, updates itself, and then updates the real DOM.

Traditionally, with regular DOM elements and regular DOM, there is no diff occurring (and so you don't have two versions of DOM elements, new and old, you just have the one single version that you are mutating as you go). So instead of sending a new version of the DOM element to be diffed, you just update the existing DOM element.

further reading:

**[React Elements vs React Components vs Component Backing Instances](https://medium.com/@fay_jai/react-elements-vs-react-components-vs-component-backing-instances-14d42729f62#.fr5n0qu0j)**

Answer (score 2):

React components can be modified by props or state. State is internal to the component. Props are passed from the parent component. Any mutations on DOM should be made via props or state changes. Though some jQuery code works with React, it is highly discouraged.

Comment: This question was more about ReactElements vs DOM Elements and why Facebook says ReactElements are immutable while DOM Elements are mutable-- not so much about if one should be using jQuery with React.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be reading too deep into that statement. I believe by the word immutable, the ReactJS documentation is saying that "this will not change between the moment we define to the moment that we use it".

I believe this comes from other frameworks such as old version of ASP.NET that changed the DOM object ID and changed other aspects of the DOM element created between the moment of creation and the moment of usage in the DOM.

However, this element can still be modified once it is actually rendered onto the DOM as a regular HTML element by jQuery. The beauty and downside to the DOM is that once anything is placed into the DOM, the validity of that data cannot be trusted. At the end of the day, it's just a document. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: After more research, I think this has to do with the virtual DOM. So react usually takes your ReactComponent, turns it into a ReactElement(s), which are ran against your current virtual DOM (the diffing), which after the virtual DOM updates to the most recent version and then finally the virtual DOM re-renders the real DOM. So, a ReactElement will have two version (current and new), so the diff can happen. With regular DOM elements and regular DOM, there is no diff. So instead of having two versions of the DOM element for diffing, you just update the single DOM element. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good. After more reading, I also found that jQuery does not play nicely when modifying React components. I would emulate anything you are trying to do with jQuery with a similar method in React. jQuery will work fine for anything else, but don't use it modify virtual DOM components.

Comment: I suspect this is because jQuery is mutating the actual ReactElement, instead of having two version (old and new)